# Display a specific hierarchical level of a specific custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

How do I adapt the following snippet to apply to a specific custom taxonomy? It current applies to post categories

I use the function below with this: `<?php display_cat_level(X,true); ?>` in my theme files to display each  hierarchical category level

```
function get_level($category, $level = 0)
{
    if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
        return $level;
    } else {
        $level++;
        $category = get_category($category->category_parent);
        return get_level($category, $level);
    }
}

function display_cat_level( $level = 0 , $link=false){

    $cats = get_the_category( );
    if( $cats ){
        foreach($cats as $cat){
            $current_cat_level = get_level($cat);
            if( $current_cat_level  == $level ){
                if($link==true) {
                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">'.$cat->name."</a>";
                } else {
                    echo $cat->name."";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Answer**: These updates from Jacob allows the original and updated functions to work together...

```
<?php 
function get_level_subject($category, $level = 0)
{
    if ($category->parent == 0) {
        return $level;
    } else {
        $level++;
        $category = get_term( $category->parent );
        return get_level_subject($category, $level);
    }
}

function display_cat_level_subject( $level = 0 , $link=false){

    $cats = get_the_terms( null, 'subject' );
    if( $cats ){
        foreach($cats as $cat){
            $current_cat_level = get_level_subject($cat);
            if( $current_cat_level  == $level ){
                if($link==true) {
                    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link( $cat->term_id ).'">'.$cat->name."</a>";
                } else {
                    echo $cat->name."";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

- `get_the_category()` to `get_the_terms( null, 'taxonomy_name' )`.
- `get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID )` to `get_term_link( $cat->term_id )`.
- `get_category( $category->category_parent )` to `get_term( $category->parent )`.

If you want to use the same function for multiple taxonomies, you can accept the taxonomy name as an argument and pass it to the first item above:

```
function display_cat_level( $level = 0 , $link = false, $taxonomy = 'category' ){
    $cats = get_the_terms( null, $taxonomy );
    // etc.
}
```

Also, even when working with categories, don't use `cat_ID` and `category_parent`. Those were deprecated 11 years ago in favour of `term_id` and `parent`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, If I ask nicely would you be able to update the function with term_id and parent :)

Comment: My lists of changes includes that.

Comment: It's not displaying how the original function works. For example when I used '<?php display_cat_level(0,true); ?>' it dosplays the top parent category, but with the new '<?php display_cat_level_subject(0,true); ?>' it displays all the parent/child taxonomies not the individual one.

Comment: I missed a line. On the third line of your question's code, `$category->category_parent` should also be `$category->parent`.

Comment: It works as per my updated question

Comment: So you're all good now?

Comment: Yes, it all works